# Why are my localhost HTTP response times so slow?

Tags: performance, tomcat

Using localhost and Tomcat 7, I'm seeing between 600-800ms *per request* in Chrome Developer tools for a specific webapp. Requests are JS files, CSS files, images or the initial server response. Some responses are less than 1KB, others are over 100KB.

As a result, it's taking around 10 seconds to load one page of the webapp. When I load the same webapp on our production server, it's taking less than 1 second to load an entire page.

I'm not sure where to continue debugging the issue...

- I've ruled out it being a browser issue by testing in Safari too.
- I've turned it off and on again

  - Reduced response to 500-600ms overall
- I've cleared out my log files
- I've ruled out the webapp's frontend entirely by hitting a resource directly, ex: `http://ts.xyz.com:9091/1.0/toolsList/javascript/toolsList.js` or `http://ts.xyz.com:9091/awake`
- I've tested another webapp and that performs lightning-quick

So, it has to be this particular app and it has to be locally.

Comment: Sounds like your CSS is the culprit, any more info or examples of your CSS?

Comment: There are 5 CSS files, but this wouldn't explain why a direct resource would be very slow as well, such as a JSON endpoint.

Comment: What does the URL look like? Is it like "http://localhost:8000/...", "http://192.168.1.100:8000/..." or "http://machine.localdomain:8000/..."? Is it on Windows? What version?

Comment: Try troubleshooting problems with your installations and/or hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen such behaviour long time ago when the webserver (Apache httpd back then) was configured to make DNS lookups for logs - these took awfully long time especially when an IP could not be resolved. As it doesn't make sense for a localhost app to be orders of magnitude slower (especially when you're talking about serving static resources) I'd check for any network related issues: Database connections, logging configurations, DNS lookups, TLS server trust issues (with backends, database, LDAP or others).

I can't decide if I add this as "if everything else fails" or rather add this as "but first try this:"... you decide:

Compare the setup of your production server with your development server (localhost) and make extra extra *extra* sure that there's no meaningful difference.

Comment: "network related issues" was key... it appears to be only when I'm connected to my workplace VPN as once I get into the office the problem goes away entirely